# PhalconPHP - Unable to load a component from the DI in a controller

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to create an ACL component as a service, for a multi-module PhalconPHP application. When I call the ACL component from the Controller Base, I am getting an error that I can't re-declare the ACL class.

Any ideas how to fix it, and understand the logic of why it is re-initialized again?

Fatal error: Cannot declare class X\Acl\Acl because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\app\common\Acl\Acl.php on line 12

Update:
If I changed everything to "Pacl" then it works. I assume there might be a mixup with the PhalconPHP namespace. I am either not using the namespaces properly, or there's a bug in PhalconPHP 2.1 Beta 2.

```
/app/common/Acl/Acl.php
namespace X\Acl;
use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component;
use Phalcon\Acl;
use Phalcon\Acl\Role as AclRole;
use Phalcon\Acl\Resource as AclResource;

/*
 *  ACL component
 */
class Acl extends Component {
    private function initialize() {
    }
    public function isAllowed() {
        die('called');
    }
}


/app/front/controllers/ControllerBase.php
namespace X\Front\Controllers;
use Phalcon\Session as Session;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;

class ControllerBase extends Controller {
    public function beforeExecuteRoute(Dispatcher $dispatcher) {
        //$this->acl = $this->getDI()->get("acl");
        var_dump($this->acl->isAllowed()); //same behavior in both case
    }
}

/app/front/Module.php
namespace X\Front;
use Phalcon\DiInterface;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use X\Acl\Acl as Acl;

class Module {
    public function registerAutoloaders() {
        $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

        $loader->registerNamespaces(array(
            'X\Front\Controllers' => __DIR__ . '/controllers/',
            'X\Front' => __DIR__,
            'X' => __DIR__ . '/../common/'
        ));

        $loader->register();
    }
    public function registerServices(DiInterface $di) {
        $di['acl'] = function() {
            return new Acl();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Try by registering service as shared service..

Comment: I think I'm overwriting the ACL namespace with my own somehow.. or there's a bug in the Phalcon 2.1Beta2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Phalcon issue. Look closely at your code:

```
namespace X\Acl;

use Phalcon\Acl;

class Acl extends ... {

}
```

What **Acl** interpreter should use? `X\Acl\Acl` or `Phalcon\Acl`?
The same error you get for example for the following code

```
namespace My\Awesome\Ns;

use Some\Name; # Name 1

class Name # Name 2
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't even notice that :)